# Handling integer out of range in bash

Tags: bash, awk, biginteger

I have collected vmstat data in a file . It gives details about free, buffer and cache .
SInce i'm interested in finding the memory usage , I should do the following computation for each line of vmstat output -- USED=TOTAL - (FREE+BUFFER+CACHE) where TOTAL is the total RAM  memory and USED is the instantaneous memory value.
TOTAL memory = 4042928 (4 GB)

My code is here

```
grep -v procs $1 | grep -v free | awk '{USED=4042928-$4-$5-$6;print $USED}' > test.dat
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
        FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1
```

Comment: The `awk` error implies too many input fields (can you how us what 1 line of your input looks like?) rather than a math error.

Comment: My input file looks like this upto the  6th field...

0  2 180728  25172    664   8520

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be printing `$USED` for a start, the variable in `awk` is `USED`:

```
pax> vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0 1402804 258392 2159316    0    0    54    79  197  479  1  2 93  3

pax> vmstat | egrep -v 'procs|free' | awk '{USED=4042928-$4-$5-$6;print USED}'
222780
```

What is most likely to be happening in your case is that you're using an `awk` with that limitation of about 32000 fields per record.

Because your fields `4`, `5` and `6` are respectively `25172`, `664` and `8520` (from one of your comments), your `USED` value becomes `4042928-25172-664-8520` or `4008572`.

If you tried to print `USED`, that's what you'd get but, because you're trying to print `$USED`, it thinks you want `$4008572` (field number 4008572) which is just a *little* bit beyond the 32000 range.

Interestingly, if you have a lot more free memory, you wouldn't get the error but you'd still get an erroneous value :-)

By the way, `gawk` doesn't have this limitation, it simply prints an empty field (see, for example, section 11.9 [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/unixnut3/chapter/ch11.html)).

Answer (score 2):

you can just do it with one awk command

```
vmstat | awk 'NR>2{print 4042928-$4-$5-$6 }' file
```